# Pandas : How to get timestamp.day and timestamp.month with padded zero

Tags: pandas, date-range, strftime, strptime

```
rng = pd.date_range('2016-02-07', periods=7, freq='D')
print(rng[0].day)
print(rng[0].month)

7
2
```

I want the output with a padded zero. i.e :

```
07
02
```

a)Is there any ready function to change the format of the .day and .month?

b)Is there any other way to get day and month with padded zero ?

I have already tried the following :

```
rng = pd.date_range('2016-02-07', periods=7, freq='D')
r=str(rng[0])

d = datetime.strptime(r[:10], '%Y-%m-%d') #[:10] this removes time from date
z= (date.strftime(d, "%d"))
print(z)
```

output:

```
07
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC you can use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
In [8]:
rng = pd.date_range('2016-02-07', periods=7, freq='D')
days = rng.strftime('%d')
months = rng.strftime('%m')
print(days)
print(months)

['07' '08' '09' '10' '11' '12' '13']
['02' '02' '02' '02' '02' '02' '02']
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `rng` is of `Timestamp` dtype:

```
rng[0]
Timestamp('2016-02-07 00:00:00', offset='D')
```

Timestamps can be formatted with a standard c-type function `strftime` like:

```
rng[0].strftime('%d')
'07'
rng[0].strftime('%m')
'02'
```

Please note, these are strings.

You may find additional info on formatting datetime here https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Thank you Sergey. Yes the output is a string, I need to convert it to appropriate format.